# how to get width of element that width is responsive or auto

Tags: jquery

i am try to get width of `li` by jquery

i have list like

```
  <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Advance Server and Server Confing</li>
  <li>FaQ</li>
  </ul>
```

so try to get width of `li` and i am trying this

```
$( "#main_menu ul li" ).each(function() {
     alert($("#main_menu ul li").width());  
});
```

it give me same width of each `li`. i also try `.outerWidth()` function but it give me same width.

Comment: because irrespective of the content all `li` element takes same width http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YXnQ7/1/

Comment: also see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YXnQ7/2/

Comment: inspect the elements with firebug, each element is having same width :)

Comment: thanks Arun, but if i want to set a arrow image in right of background of li then it not take proper position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <ul>
  <li><span>Home</span></li>
  <li><span>Advance Server and Server Confing</span></li>
  <li><span>FaQ</span></li>
  </ul> 


$( "ul li span" ).each(function() {
    alert($(this).width());  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48Apj/

Answer (score -2):

You are using `each` that's why you get the width for each of them.

Try using it for a single one, and try out `(this)` which will ensure you get the result from the current element only. You can use `attr` too.

```
$('#main_menu ul li').click(function () {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/t39Yk/

For you, you can use `width` instead of `id`.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/t39Yk/1/ (fiddle with width)